# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultSize')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I'm trying to useState in my MERN project, and I have defaultSize defined in MongoDB, and am trying to useState by `product.defaultSize`. If I change some of my code (like adding console.log("hello")) and save it, the error disapears and loads fine. But if I refresh the page the error comes back?

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { getProductDetails } from "../redux/actions/productActions";

import { SizeOptions } from '../components/SizeOptions';

const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.getProductDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

    const [ src, setSrc ] = useState(product.defaultSize);


    useEffect(() => {
    if (product && match.params.id !== product._id) {
        dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
        }
    }, [dispatch, match, product]);
    
    <div className='sizebuttons'>
        {product && (product.size || []).map((size, index) => (<SizeOptions  key={index} size={size} changeSrc={src => setSrc(src)}/>))}
    </div>
    
return (
    <model-viewer
        id="model-viewer"
        src={src}
        alt={product.productName}
        ar
        ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look"
        ar-placement="floor"
        shadow-intensity="1"
        camera-controls
        min-camera-orbit={product.mincameraorbit} 
        max-camera-orbit={product.maxcameraorbit}
        interaction-prompt="none">  
            <button slot="ar-button" className="ar-button">
                View in your space
            </button>
    </model-viewer>
)};
```

I've tried also changing it to `useState(product?.defaultSize);` as I saw another post on here saying that could work, but I had no luck with it. And as you can tell, all the other `product.otherstuff` works just fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `product.otherstuff` works fine because you're checking if it's truthy first (`product &&`). `product` must be initially undefined and you'll need to account for it.

Comment: What exactly didn't work with the nullsafe version? Just that it didn't use the correct initial value?

Comment: I am unsure why it didn't work, I think it's because `product.defaultSize` is a URL to a 3D model. And the `?` maybe made it an invalid URL? I'm fairly new to React, so all of my code has been self-taught and a lot of trial and error so far. I've also tried adding `const product = product.defaultSize'` to then use `useState(product)` but that still did not work.

Comment: I think I got a little closer, I changed useState to `useState(product && product.defaultSize)`, and it'll load every time without error now. But now it'll load the pervious page's content first and then if I refresh the page it'll load the current page's content. So I think I'm still pretty far off. Going to keep messing around with it!

Comment: Long awaited update: I got a little closer, but still not there yet. If I set it to `useState([] || product.defaultSize);` it'll load blank first, and once I make a selection it'll load the product. Even if I navigate to another page it won't load my previous selections now. Still not loading the `defaultSize` automatically once the page is loaded, but it's closer I think..

Comment: `useState([] || product.defaultSize)` -- this won't work how you expect because an empty array is truthy.

Comment: I guess I am having a hard time understanding what truthy means haha. I have it declared in my database what defaultSize is and if I `console.log(product.defaultSize)` it'll give me the correct log. Could you point me in the right direction on where I could learn more about how to make something truthy/not truthy? Or explain a little further please?

Comment: `a || b` means use `a` unless it is falsy, in which case use `b` instead. The problem is `[]` is considered truthy, not falsy, so `product.defaultSize` will *never* be used. Perhaps you mean to do `product.defaultSize || []`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: I actually did try that as well before posting, and it would still throw `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaultSize')`. Thank you for the link, I will read up on it now!

Comment: My goodness I finally got it to work! I think.. so if I actually set `useState();` and set my `src={src || product.defaultSize}` in my model-viewer component instead. It works perfectly now! Thank you for the help though and providing me some ideas on how to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { getProductDetails } from "../redux/actions/productActions";

import { SizeOptions } from '../components/SizeOptions';

const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.getProductDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

    const [ src, setSrc ] = useState();


    useEffect(() => {
    if (product && match.params.id !== product._id) {
        dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
        }
    }, [dispatch, match, product]);
    
    <div className='sizebuttons'>
        {product && (product.size || []).map((size, index) => (<SizeOptions  key={index} size={size} changeSrc={src => setSrc(src)}/>))}
    </div>
    
return (
    <model-viewer
        id="model-viewer"
        src={src || product.defaultSize}
        alt={product.productName}
        ar
        ar-modes="scene-viewer quick-look"
        ar-placement="floor"
        shadow-intensity="1"
        camera-controls
        min-camera-orbit={product.mincameraorbit} 
        max-camera-orbit={product.maxcameraorbit}
        interaction-prompt="none">  
            <button slot="ar-button" className="ar-button">
                View in your space
            </button>
    </model-viewer>
)};
```